# How to port from java.util.Optional method call chaining to Guava Optional?

Tags: java, java-8, guava, option-type

I have the following that uses java.util.optional

```
// this works fine for java.util.Optional
Optional <Context> xx = Optional.ofNullable(x);
Optional<DateRange> dates = xx.map(Context::getEntity).map(Entitiy::getDates);
```

However, I need to convert that to use guava's optional.  I tried something like guava Optional transform but I'm unsure how to chain something like this with guava optional?

```
// guava...how can I chain method calls as such...this fails of course
Optional <Context> xx = Optional.of(x);
Optional<DateRange> dates = xx.get().getEntity().getDates();
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: So, where is the attempt using transform()? Why do you need to go from the newest, standard Java 8 to the older, non-standard Guava? I love Guava, but when there is a standard Java equivalent, you should favor the standard.

Comment: @JBNizet Having in mind OP's earlier question, apparently he is porting this to pre-Java 8.

Comment: OP, you are chasing wild geese here. The only reason why Optional is useful are lambdas/method references. If you want to rewrite this to pre-Java 8, you'll be substituting an anonymous class declaration for each method reference/lambda.

Comment: yes, exactly what @MarkoTopolnik stated in first statement.  Java8 byte code issues that I don't have control over.  Also, I have lambdas that will need replaced which is why i'd still like to at least port to guava.  thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be almost exactly the same. Just methods' name are different, but usage is exactly the same.

Just keep in mind that Guava's *Optional.of()* and Java8's *Optional.ofNullable()* are not the same. You should use Guava's *Optional.fromNullable()* instead.

Guava's *Optional.transform()* is equal to Java8's *Optional.map()*.

```
Optional<Context> xx = Optional.fromNullable(x);
Optional<DateRange> dates = xx.transform(Context::getEntity).transform(Entitiy::getDates);
```

If you are not using Java8, you won't be able to use lambdas and method references, so you will have to go on with anonymous classes implementing *Function* interface:

```
xx.transform(new Function<Context, Entity>() {
        @Override
        public Entity apply(Context c) {
            return c.getEntity();
        }
    })
```

and so on

Comment: awesome, thanks so much!  i was trying to chain the calls together within one transform (y)